# Jquery: submenu appears with hover function but not click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, hover, jquery-hover

I have a multi-layered navigation the consists of 3 `<ul>`s nested in each other (obviously a menu with hidden submenus the show on click).

I have created a script to show the 2nd level `<ul>`s if one of the first is clicked. This works fine:

```
//CLICK MAIN NAV SHOW 2nd LAYER NAV
$("#ctamenu ul li").not("#ctamenu ul li ul li, .thirdsub").click(function() {
  $(this).children('ul').stop().delay(200).slideDown(300);
});//END CLICK FUNCTION
```

But when I repeat this for the 3rd level `<ul>`s it does not work properly:

```
$("#ctamenu ul li ul li").click(function () {
    $(this).find('.thirdsub').stop().show(300);
  });
```

What is strange is that when I inspect the elements in the browser the `display: none` css is definitely removed from the thirdsub element. I even get a coloured outline where Chrome is showing me where the element should be.

What even weirder is that if I change .click to .hover it works fine:

```
$("#ctamenu ul li ul li").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).find('.thirdsub').stop().show(300);
  },
  function () {
    $(this).find('.thirdsub').stop().hide(300);
  }
);
```

Would anyone know why this could be working with hover but not click?

Comment: u better show||check ur css&html settings. p.s. demo would be opportunely

Comment: Do you have an example to look at? Might be caused by different things, is `visibility` set to `hidden` or is it positioned with a `z-index`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#ctamenu ul li ul li").click(function (e) {
    $(this).find('.thirdsub').stop().show(300);
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Try `stopPropagation()` because you also have assigned `click` handler to parent of that. Which will invoke also when you click on `#ctamenu ul li ul li`.